# How to disable the maximize button in window.open popup for chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

How to disable or remove the maximize button in window.open popup for chrome browser?

```
window.open("google.com", 'googlePopup', 'location=no,resizable=no,directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,width=550,height=415,top=120,dialog=yes');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Deliberately malicious actions are generally restricted by browsers.